# Is it possible to get 2 methods cal in same page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

These are the two methods i need to return on same JSP page. Unable to return pharmacysuccess jsp page to pharmacylist jsp page

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/pharmacylist" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
            List<PharmacyMaster> pharmacyMaster = pharmacyService.findAllPharmacyMasters();
            model.addAttribute("pharmacyMaster", pharmacyMaster);
            model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
            return "pharmacy/pharmacylist";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-pharmacy-{row_id}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updatePharmacyMaster(@Valid PharmacyMaster pharmacyMaster,
                BindingResult result, ModelMap model, @PathVariable int row_id) {

            /* checking the pharmacy form have any error. */
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "/pharmacy/addpharmacy";
            }

            pharmacyMaster.setModifiedDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));
            pharmacyService.updatePharmacyMaster(pharmacyMaster);

            model.addAttribute("success", "pharmacy " + pharmacyMaster.getPharmacyName()
                    + " updated successfully");
            model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
            return "/pharmacy/pharmacylist";
        }
```

Comment: PLEASE edit your code to a readable format.

Comment: Please read this and reformat your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Should these not be the same? i.e. the additional slash at the start:

```
return "pharmacy/pharmacylist";

return "/pharmacy/pharmacylist";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that / on the begin makes you a problem. See how your view resolver looks like. If it have / on the end, then I think that maybe a problem is that you have that / on the end of the resolver and \ here on begin and that are 2 /, which is not good.